# Scanning electron microscopy (SEM) images without Conductive Samples

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, microscopy

The traditional understanding for obtaining scanning electron microscopy (SEM) images is that one first needs to coat the specimen in gold (or similar).

This is supposedly necessary because biological samples do not conduct, which causes electrons to remain in the sample where the built-up charge interferes with the electron beam and leads to image distortion.  As I understand it, having a conductive sample is not the main principle of SEM, but I am still not sure how new microscopes like [this one](https://www.hitachi-hightech.com/global/science/products/microscopes/electron-microscope/tabletop-microscopes/tm4000ii.html) are able to obtain good surface detail with non-conductive samples which have not been specially prepared.  What is the principle which enables this to be possible?

Comment: Multiple engineering tweaks - lower operating voltages available (so less charge induced in insulators), better detectors so less charge needs (so less charge built up), operation in worse vacuum allowing more charge bleed-off, etc...

Comment: This probably isnt what they are doing, but for a given material there will be one beam energy at which your sample accumulates zero charge. Typically samples gain positive charge due to emitting multiple secondary electrons per primary electron. Reducing the beam energy reduces the ratio. Also, not using high magnification helps.